# How to switch to design mode in CS Cart 4 beta

Tags: cs-cart

Hi i have downloaded the cs cart 4 ultimate and i want to switch to the design mode. As i have read this example and it is CS-CART 3.0.1

http://joejiko.com/blog/web-development/cscart-301-design-mode-view-storefront-customization-mode-working-solved/

Can any body please help how to switch mode in CS CART 4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the front end and the back end as the admin user - that brings up the debug tools etc.